# Progress Bar in WPF - stuck in 50%

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a class with a BackgroundWorker and a ProgressBar on its GUI like this

```
public class mCrypt
{
   public byte[] DataBlock;
   public byte[] IVBlock;
   public static Bitmap FingerprintImg;
   public byte[] TempX;
   public byte[] TempAngles;
   public byte[] TempY;
   public byte[] TempKey;
   public byte[] X;
   public byte[] Y;
   public byte[] Angles;
   public byte[] Key;
   public int NoM;

   public mCrypt(BackgroundWorker bw, string imgLoc, string fileLoc, byte[] ivBlock)
   {
      if (!bw.CancellationPending)
      {
         bw.ReportProgress(0);
         LoadImg(imgLoc);
         bw.ReportProgress(7);
         DetectMinutiae(FingerprintImg);
         bw.ReportProgress(25);
         ConvertValues();
         bw.ReportProgress(30);
         LoadFile(fileLoc);
         // This LoadFile method contains DataBlock = File.ReadAllBytes(fileloc);
         bw.ReportProgress(35);
         HandleLength(ivBlock);
         bw.ReportProgress(40);
         ManageInitKey();
         bw.ReportProgress(45);
         GenerateKey();
         bw.ReportProgress(50);
      }
   }

   public byte[] EncryptFile(BackgroundWorker bgw)
   {
      if(!bw.CancellationPending)
      {
         for(int i = 0, i < (DataBlock.Length / 16), i++)
         {
            //Doing cryptographical process here
            ...
            //ProgressBar updates
            if((i / (DataBlock.Length / 16)) + 50 != 100)
               bgw.ReportProgress((i / (DataBlock.Length / 16)) + 50);
            else
               bgw.ReportProgress(100);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As I tried to run the app, the ProgressBar only updates when constructor runs. Leaving the ProgressBar in 50% state until the process finish. I don't understand why it didn't work. Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have stepped thru the code are you hitting the bgw.ReportProgress calls?

Comment: Its the worst way to implement. implement this by using async/await.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using your `BackgroundWorker` correctly, and you're locking the UI thread.

Move the calls to `LoadImg()`, `LoadFile();` and `ReportProgress()` into the `DoWork` event. Also, you may have to modify what those methods are doing, if they touch the UI at all.

I'd also recommend reading this: [Threading in C#: BackgroundWorker](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker)

Comment: I still don't get it, which calls should I move? the ReportProgress() or the BackgroundWorker? if I move the ReportProgress() into the DoWork event, how should I assign the percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Do not touch the `UI thread` from the `background worker` process directly.
Use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to modify the `UI`

*Inside worker process thread:*

```
    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
    {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded,new Action(()=>
                            {
                                //code that changes progress-bar
                            }
                           ));
     }
```